# Can not run docker container from compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.1

I can not run a `Net Core` application in `docker-compose`  due to this error,while i can start the container from `dockerfile`.

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

My `dockerfile` uses the `.dll` directly (i am directly using the `publish` directory), so no `build` ,`restore` is required.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
EXPOSE 8202
```

I run:
`docker build -t mp . 
docker run --name mp0 -d myimg` and it works.

However when i am running it from `compose` :

```
 mp:
        image: mp
        container_name: mp0
        build: ./mpbuild
        ports:
          - 8302:8202
```

I have tried using :`aspnetcore`,`aspnetcore-build`,`aspnetcore-runtime` to no avail .I keep getting asked about the `SDK`.

P.S: The app is version `aspnetcore 2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore` to `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.That did it.The funny part is that i had another container with a `.Net Core 2.1 App` that was starting fine with the settings mentioned above,and i couldn't pin point why this one didn't work.